# Spring JPA Exposing/Mapping @JsonIgnore fields from an associated Entity using custom query @Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I have 2 entities (Department, Employee) with a Bi-Directional One-To-Many relationship.
1 Department has MANY Employee.
`Department` owns the `Employee`

I annotated `department` field with `@JsonIgnore` so that `Department` information is not serialized when I `GET localhost:8080/employee`

I created a custom query to expose all information of `Employee` including which `Department` the employee belongs.

**Department** Model

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
   ...
}
```

**Employee** Model

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Department department;
    ...
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT e.*, d.department_name FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d ON e.department_id = d.id WHERE e.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Employee findEmployeeByIdWithDepartment(Long employeeId);
}
```

The query works fine in H2-Console SQL Editor. `DEPARTMENT_ID`, `DEPARTMENT_NAME` information is being included if I do a `GET localhost:8080/employee/1`

[image]

However, in Postman, I only get `Employee` information (id,firstname,lastname,middlename) only. The `Department` where the `Employee` belongs is **NOT being mapped/serialized** (because I used `@JsonIgnored` in `Employee` class).

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "middleName": "Doe",
    "lastName": "Johnny"
}
```

If I change the return type of `findEmployeeByIdWithDepartment` to `Object`, I can get `Employee` information **along with** the `Department` where employee belongs.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT e.*, d.department_name FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d ON e.department_id = d.id WHERE e.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Object findEmployeeByIdWithDepartment(Long employeeId);
}
```

RESULT: (Not the desired JSON format of nesting `Department` info)

```
[
    1,
    "John",
    "Johnny",
    "Doe",
    1,
    "Accounting"
]
```

I am not sure how to be able to display the `Department` information along with `Employee` information if I do a `GET localhost:8080/employee/1`
AND
still be able to do a `GET localhost:8080/department` without issue.

Without `@JsonIgnore` on `department` field IN `Employee` class, the Json response will result in StackOverflow or Endless nested serialization issue.

Thank you.

Comment: why you want to get d.department_name seperatly in your query?try to get e.* just and set your return type to Employee instead of Object.you can access to Employee.getDepartment and then get the name and rest of the fields from Department field

Answer (score 0):

You can write getters for the Depertment-properties in Employee, something like

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Department department;

    @JsonProperty("departmentId")
    public Long getDepartmentId()
    {
        return department.getId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("departmentName")
    public String getDepartmentName()
    {
        return department.getName();
    }

    ...

}
```